# group by multiple columns and perfume custom aggregation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe which has multiple id's and facid's. I want to group by the three columns and apply a custom function or use built in pivot function to get the expected output.
input is like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [18614, 18614, 18614, 18650, 18650, 18709, 18709],
'facid': [140065, 140065, 140065, 140339, 140339, 140702, 140703],
'location': ['dc','dc','dc','md','md','md','va'],
'key': [433,442,443, 434, 444, 442, 443],
'value1':['yes',7,3,'yes',4,5,6],
'value2':['stage1','NA','NA','stage2','NA','NA','NA']})
```

and I expect the output be like this... I also want to set a default value of 999 for the two numeric columns

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [18614,18650,18709,18709],
'facid': [140065, 140339, 140702, 140703],
'location': ['dc','md','md','va'],
'length':[7,999,5,999],
'width':[3,999,999,6],
'stage': ['stage1','stage2','None','None']})
```

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy any idea what might be the possible solution for my question?

Comment: kindly add your expected output as code or table in your question, without the redirection to the pics.

Comment: @sammywemmy I added my expected output as a code. I hope this make sense.

Comment: kindly recheck your custom function, it seems incorrect. there is no depth column in df2, when key is 442, value is 7 or 5, so how do you decide which? same goes for 443 which is either 3 or 6

Comment: What I was trying to do is group by those three columns and add a three new columns (length, depth, stage) based on key column condition. For example... whenever key is 442, set the "width' to 7, when key is 443 set the 'depth' 3 and when key is either 433 or 434 set 'stage' to whatever in the 'value' column.
My custom logic might not be right or needs modification I guess. But what I want to do is to kind of convert multiple rows (grouped rows) into one based on the logic I have tried to explain above. I hope it is a little clearer now. Thanks

Comment: a bit clearer, where is the 999 coming from?

Comment: that is for default. for instance... 18709 id at 'md' location has 442 and will get the width as 5 but it doesn't have 443 so it gets a default value of 999 or none ... the none existed key's doesn't really matter for now

Comment: ok. gimme a minute. looks more like a pivot operation would fit in better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you have in mind;

`np.select` is a much faster way to do conditionals in Pandas/numpy compared to if/else.

Get the new values for `key` based on conditions, pivot the data, fillna with default values, and do some cleanups:

```
 index = ["id", "facid", "location"]
(
    df1.assign(
        key=np.select(
            [df1.key.isin([433, 434]), df1.key == 442, df1.key == 443],
            ["stage", "length", "width"],
            "ignore",
        ),
        # assumption here is that `NA` is a string, not null
        value2 = np.where(df1.value2=="NA", 
                          df1.value1, 
                          df1.value2)

    )
    .pivot(index, "key", "value2")
    .drop(columns="ignore")
    .fillna({"length": 999, "width": 999})
    .reindex(columns=["length", "width", "stage"])
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index()
)


      id   facid location  length  width   stage
0  18614  140065       dc       7      3  stage1
1  18650  140339       md     999    999  stage2
2  18709  140702       md       5    999     NaN
3  18709  140703       va     999      6     NaN
```

Comment: Hi @Sisay; no worries. Kindly add the update to your original question, with expected output. easier for me(and any one else) to grok

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, I updated the original question with appropriate input and expected output. Thanks